# Found a Windows 3.1 machine. How do I get the uptime?

Tags: windows, uptime, windows-3.1

I have found a very old machine at a company storage room. It seems to have been running forever.
It is not connected to the Internet and only has a 3.5" floppy drive.

Is it possible to look up the uptime for this machine?

[image]

Comment: That is just cool! Did you find out how long its been running?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 3.1 (and WfW 3.11) do maintain an uptime counter, but it is only available by an API call so you need a program to see it. If you can get it on the machine then [this](http://www.uselesssoftware.com/download/uptime-zip) will tell you what you want to know.

EDIT: Apparently that one isn't the correct file, [here is a different one](http://www.shdon.com/files/uptime.zip) I found that seems to be correct, the original reference I found was [here](http://www.shdon.com/software/tools).

Supposedly from command prompt you can run `net statistics server` and see the start time of the computer, but it's buried and with no `grep` command in Windows it is hard to find.

Comment: Well, that program did not work. It just showed the time since the program started :(

Comment: Dang it... I remember doing this "back in the day" and the program was called uptime, I googled it and found the one linked above and the description looked correct, so I posted the answer... sorry it isn't the right one. I will look a little more.

Comment: @Chengy See edits to answer... might work better. Yes, I want to know the uptime of that box too :) and what is has been running for so long.